# How to stop the form loading event and return to mdi parent? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a base form and many other forms Inherits from my Base form..  I want the base form and all the other forms inherited from her to check a condition on my base forms load event and stop everything from loading if its false and return to mdi parent.. Any ideas.?

```
    Private Sub LayoutManagerForm_v2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TagId = Me.Tag

    If (gridLayoutRepository.checkPrivileges(TagId) = False) Then
        MsgBox("Sorry, you have no privileges to open this form!")
        Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Close))
    End If


End Sub
```

Thats the Load event from my Base form..  Its working but the other forms inherits from this are loading withought a problem..  I want to stop them from loading..  How can i do this..???

[ex.1 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0V1f.png)

For example when i click "Seller Transactions -> Seller Transactions(Incomes)" as you can see above in the ex.1 img, i want if the user has no permission to open the "Seller transactions Form" to return back to this main window -> (ex.2 img).

[ex.2 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOSBH.jpg)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem, going to need more details...

Comment: Why not check permissions further upstream and do something like disable the menu or button if they do not have permission?  please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Yeap...  But how i can do this..??  Idle_mind tell what details you need to sent you plz.. And sorry guys i didn't answered earlier but i had another project going and i forgot about ths one..

Comment: To be more specific..  When i am invoking close() method in parent form, why the child form inheriting from parent form still opening... I want to stop the loading of the parent form and the child forms... I just want to do the checking in parent form cause i have 140 forms inheriting from parent.. But after the program is running the code inside parent's form load event, is running the code inside child's load event too..